# go-redis does it have support for registering / executing lua functions

Tags: redis, go-redis

From its version 7.x onwards, Redis has introduced functions, as an alternative to script execution, as documented [here](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/functions-intro/).

I am looking for an example, or documentation on how to use redis functions using go-redis package.  Not sure, if go-redis supports this feature yet.

Thanks for anyone letting me know about this.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a bit more in the official documentation of go-redis, which has a way of executing unsupported commands using the `Do`, as mentioned [here](https://redis.uptrace.dev/guide/go-redis.html#executing-unsupported-commands).

```
// Defind the function code..
fcode := `#!lua name=mylib 
    redis.register_function('myfunc', 
      function (keys, args) 
          return args[1] 
      end)`


// Load or replace the function
val, err := rdb.Do(ctx, "function", "load", "replace", "<function code text>").Result()

// later in the code... call the function
va, err := rdb.Do(ctx, "fcall", "myfunc", 0, "hello").Result()
```